# Limit Comment Line Count - Add Read More Button

Tags: comments

Is it possible to limit how many lines of comment are displayed with the option to load more?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Greg's Comment Length Limiter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/321945/limit-comment-line-count-add-read-more-button). It provides you with a configurable limit on the length of comments.

Comment: I don't want to limit the length just the output length. Our comments can be a bit like stack exchanges answers and can be very long.